# Are java .class files needed after an application is running?

Tags: java, git, classloader

I had a hard time writing the title to this question, but here is my situation and what I am asking:

- I have a Java project that I run "ant test" on to run the tests
- The tests take about 10 minutes to run
- Can I switch to a different Git branch in the middle of running these tests without consequences?
- I want the tests to complete against the original code, and allow me to simply work on a different branch while that happens.

I guess the root of my question is: **Are .class files needed after the application is loaded and running?**  Is the classes just stored in memory, and I don't need the files on the file system anymore?  Or does it still access/read things on the filesystem?

Any insight or better understanding of what java needs for a running application is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes are loaded on demand.  The classloader won't attempt to load a class until that class has been referenced.  Therefore, removing class files from the classpath in the middle of a run would almost certainly cause failures.

Comment: Got it, so if somehow I knew all the classes were loaded, it would probably be okay, but there isn't really a good way of knowing this, so not safe.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you don't compile the .java files you're getting from Git to the same location while the test is running, you won't have a problem with the .class files - no matter how the IDE loads the classes.

Comment: *"Unless you compile the .java files"* in the same location while the test is running .... But the idea is sound ;)

Comment: This actually is helpful.  My "ant test" command does compile into a different location than my IDE, so I could actually checkout a different branch of .java files and not worry about the tests that are running.  The folder of .class files is obviously .gitignore'd, so this will probably work without issue.  Thanks!

Comment: I awarded the answer to Mark since it more accurately addressed my exact question, but your answer was very helpful to my certain situation.  Thanks again

Comment: @SeanAdkinson You're welcome! I rather solve the problem than answer the question :).

Answer (score 0):

In standard (i mean sun/oracle) JVM once a class is loaded it stays in memory until the jvm shut down, but it might not be loaded yet since classes are loaded on demand.

Answer (score 0):

If all the files have been loaded into the memory then it would not be needed...but then how can u make sure that all classes have been loaded into memory...so u would need class filesin the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you have to do a step backwards and rethink the solution.

You wrote, that you execute integration tests. And as a part of the test you are switching the sources, that are tested. If you do this, you will produce useless test data, because you can't be sure, what was really executed.

If you want to test two different vrsion / branches of you software, just enable two test runs and compare the results.

You can only be sure, that a *.class file is loaded, if you have used it. After löoading the class file, it stays in the memory of the JVM. Maybe it will be unloaded if it is unused for some time and the GEM-space getting low (but I don't think so).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm not trying to test both branches at once.  I am just trying to test one branch, and do some work on another one.  I want the tests to complete with the original branch's code.

Comment: try hudson or jekins. Make the integration tests not in your workspace.

Comment: We use Bamboo, but I usually try to run the tests before pushing so that I know I won't break the build for other developers.